# codeigniter, force ssl on a particular page

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, https

I'm having hard time trying to force https (ssl) to particular page on codeiginiter framework. I tried many ways, but none worked. The only way worked for me is changing the **$config['base_url']** site link to begin with **https** instead of **http**. The result was that all links were set to ssl (the entire site), which is none sense because I don't need to use the SSL everywhere. I used some php code in the login page, ut that made some troubles so I gave it up.

I want to know whether this is a good method how to do that, any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need add Condition on `.htaccess` to make use SSL port work only for selected urls.

Here is example, how to do

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} controller/function
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/controller/function[R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} controller/function
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/controller/function[R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

P.S : Your `base_url` must be set to `“/”` in your config file.
For more information check http://codeigniter.com/wiki/SSL_Handling

Comment: Thanks for the reply. BTW, are you sure this code works? I tried it and my entire site doesn't work. The browser gives an error message that my site is either down or under maintenance... any idea?

Comment: @Digitalsite depends how you want to use, there several way, from core controller, with helper. You can detect port and forward

Comment: from the link you posted, first discussion post:
"I don’t think this is a total solution.  If you want to submit sensitive information (e.g. a password) via SSL, simply using this htaccess redirect will see the information first being sent in an unencrypted request, and then again over the SSL when redirected."

Comment: @qwertzman yes but, a form where you submit post will be over SSL. For example payment page, when you click payment page, it redirects to encrypted payment page and you do your submision on encrypted page.